# Sitecore 8.1: Glass.Mapper & Razor

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, castle-windsor, glass-mapper, sitecore8.1

Running a new site on Sitecore 8.1 - installed and setup Glass.Mapper but I cannot use calls such as @RenderImage - it's complaining that i'm missing the reference to Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc, which I have already.

The following are the Nuget modules installed for Glass.Mapper:

> - BoC.Glass.Mapper
> - BoC.Glass.Mapper.Sc
> - BoC.Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor
> - Castle Windsor
> - Castle.Core
> - Glass.Mapper.Sc

I have it installed on another instance of Sitecore (7.5) - an older version of Glass.Mapper, but I've noticed that the Nuget packages do not exist anymore.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Dan

Comment: Can you add a binding redirect of old version of Glass Mapper to the new one? For ideas look at this blog - http://sitecoreblog.patrickperrone.com/2015/03/solr-glass-castle-windsor-crashers.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BoC.Glass.Mapper` is a fork of Glass Mapper, and I believe it has not been updated to V4. Remove it (and any configs that it added or deployed) and start again I say. Just add the `Glass.Mapper.Sc` nuget package will add in the correct dependencies and is compatible with Sitecore 8.1.

Just to be doubly sure, this is the correct version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glass.Mapper.Sc/

Make sure you have `Sitecore.Kernel` and `System.Web.Mvc` referenced in your project since there is a post-install step in the nuget package that adds the correct versions of Glass dlls to your project.

> To make things simpler V4 uses a Powershell script to decided which
>   references to add to your project, it checks both the Sitecore.Kernel
>   version and the System.Web.Mvc version and then installs the
>   appropriate Glass.Mapper.Sc and Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc assembly.

With regards to `@RenderImage`, either inherit your view from `GlassView<>` or better to use the extension methods, e.g. `@Html.Glass().RenderImage()`.

More info here: http://glass.lu/Blog/GlassV4